# Is the Cartesian product of $C^\infty$ functions a $C^\infty$ function?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Define the Cartesian product of two functions $f:\mathbb{R}^a\to\mathbb{R}^b$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^c\to\mathbb{R}^d$ as $$(f\times g)(x,y)=(f(x),g(y)).$$ If the function $f$ and $g$ are $C^\infty$, is the function $f\times g$ also $C^\infty$?

Comment: Yes it is. It has continuous partial derivatives s of al orders.

Comment: Hint: Note that the partial derivatives distribute independently to each component

Comment: The case $h(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ is supposedly obvious. In general the key step is to express the derivative of $t\mapsto h(tv,tw)$ in term of the partial derivatives, then the result follows easily.

Answer (score 0):

The following argument shows that $f\times g$ is $C^1$ if $f$ and $g$ are both $C^1$, and then induction and be applied to prove that it is $C^\infty$ if they are $C^\infty$.
[image]

Comment: Please, consider typing out the answer using MathJax instead of an image.